# over ride html table style table-layout-fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a html table inside a div element.

div is set to auto scroll on overflow

```
div.container {overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;}
```

what i want to achieve is - table cells be auto adjustable, but if the minimum width of any cell is crossed(say more columns are added automatically), view should be set to auto scroll.

```
<table cellspacing=0px id="tbl_iss" class="issues" style="table-layout: fixed" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr bgcolor="#D0D0D0" >
   <th width=50px style="min-width: 50px; _width: 50px;">Issue#</th>
   <th width=100px style="min-width: 100px; _width: 100px;">Abc</th>
   <th width=100px style="min-width: 100px; _width: 100px;">xyz</th>
   <th width=120px style="min-width: 100px; _width: 120px;">Pqr</th>
   <th width=200px style="min-width: 200px; _width: 200px;">Stu</th>
   <th width=120px style="min-width: 120px; _width: 120px;">efg</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

comments plz?

Comment: whatz havez you triedz so farz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables and especially table cells do not behave as one would wish regarding `width` and `height`

If you wrap the content of your table cells in a `div?  and give this`div` the width, you could be more lucky

```
<th><div style="min-width: 50px; _width: 50px;">Issue#</div></th>
```